# PSCP copy file from server to local ( from unknown sub folder)

Tags: linux, pscp

I'm trying to copy a file from server to windows local using following command

pscp.exe -pw Password User@Machinenumber:/temp/**Subfolder1**/FileName.txt C:\Users\Desktop

Above command will copy FileName.txt from subfolder1 to desktop.
Here my problem is we have multiple subfolders, **Subfolder1,Subfolder2,Subfolder3...etc**
FileName.txt would be anywhere in those sub folders(file name is constant)
Can anyone help me how to get such file using PSCP command?

Comment: Do you need directories as well? How do you diferentiate which FileName.txt is from which subfolder after copying. Moreover even if you copy it will replace and finnaly you will have only one file.

Comment: No need of directory, file name is different and it is having some known name, so there wont be any overwrite scenario.

Comment: Use -r or -R option. You should be able to solve.